# Can I measure the execution time of the Expect command in a script?

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

I am using Expect scripts for performance testing. We need to know how long each individual command takes to execute. Tell me, please, is it realistic to implement it?

I tried adding bash commands to the script, but it didn't end well

Comment: Expect uses tcl, not bash, so it's not surprising that didn't work for you.

Comment: You'll probably use the tcl [`time` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/time.htm)